# Calculation of a Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Does anyone know of a good way to calculate the residue at zero of the following function? I was able to calculate it with the higher order pole formula for residues and then used Mathematica to find the limit.  Really just looking for a nice trick without having to get too dirty.

$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(e^{-z}-1)}  $$

Thank you for any help.

By the way, the answer is $\frac{-1}{12}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{z^2(e^{-z}-1)} 
&=& \frac{1}{z^2\left(1-z+\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{6} +\ldots - 1\right)}  \\
&=& -\frac{1}{z^3\left(1-\left(\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)\right)} \\
&=& -\frac{1}{z^3}\left(1+\left(\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)+\left(\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)^2\right) \\
&=& -\frac{1}{z^3}\left(1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{12}+\ldots\right) \\
&=& -\frac{1}{z^3} - \frac{1}{2z^2} - \frac{1}{12 z} + \ldots 
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Damn I couldn't figure out how to get the series out of the denominator!! What did you do there??

Comment: @TylerHG: $1/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2+\ldots$

Comment: Oh that's sneaky ;). Very nice indeed.  Thank you kindly.

Comment: @TylerHG: Glad to help. Cheers!

Comment: Very smart! Thank you! this really helped me too!